# t[this.activeSeriesIndex].data[0] is undefined in ApexCharts. How to correctly build the series array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, typeerror, apexcharts

I'm a beginner in Vue and I'm using vue-apex chart to create a chart in my application. I want to display in chart, the values of the two component's properties "uncorrectAns" and "correctAns" that I compute thanks to a specific method (computeStat()).

```js
<template>
  <apexcharts width="500" type="bar" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexcharts>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Results',
  components: {
    apexcharts: VueApexCharts
  },

  data() {
    return {
      results: '',
      correctAns: 0,
      uncorrectAns: 0,
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          id: 'vuechart-example'
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: ['Correct Answers', 'Uncorrect Answers']
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: 'series-1',
          data: [this.correctAns, this.uncorrectAns]
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    computeStat() {
      var i
      for (i = 0; i < this.results.length; i = i + 1) {
        if (this.results[i].answerCorrect == true) {
          this.correctAns = this.correctAns + 1
        } else {
          this.uncorrectAns = this.uncorrectAns + 1
        }
      }
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.results = this.$route.params.output
    this.computeStat()
    var i
    for (i = 0; i < this.results.length; i = i + 1) {
      console.log('bestPractice ' + i + ':' + this.results[i].bestPract)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I run the application, the chart isn't displayed and I get this error message on the browser console:

[image]

I would like to know the nature of this error and if there is a correct way to display "correctAns" and "uncorrectAns" values in the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems here around your `series` property...

1. When you define `series`, both `this.correctAns` and `this.uncorrectAns` are `undefined` (this is the source of your problem)
2. Because `series` is statically defined, it will never update as you make changes to `this.correctAns` and `this.uncorrectAns`

The solution is to convert `series` into a computed property. Remove it from `data` and add

```js
computed: {
  series () {
    return [
      {
        name: 'series-1',
        data: [this.correctAns, this.uncorrectAns]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/ynLfabdz/

---

Given you seem to be treating `results` as an array, you should initialise it as such instead of an empty string, ie

```js
results: [], // not ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by simple check if the array is undefined then return empty if not return the chart with my values

```
const Amount = [
    {
        name: 'Salary Amount',
        data: salary[0] === undefined ? [] : salary
    },
    {
        name: 'Over Time Amount',
        data: overTime[0] === undefined ? [] : overTime
    },
    true
]
```